# BottomNavigationView + NavigationComponent not showing any fragment and also BottomNavigationView click is not working

Tags: android, androidx, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I have implemented bottom navigation with Navigation component but some how it's not working as expected. It doesn't load fragment UI and also it doesn't change UI when we click on another tab. If we click on same tab again, It's crashing. Please take a look this at video to get better understanding [here](https://recordit.co/jBkXLT7I7K).

It's having too many file, So i uploaded complete example project with above mentioned issue [here](https://github.com/bipinvaylu/BottomNavigationExample).

I have cross verified my implementation with `NavigationAdvancedSample` app of Android Architecture Component Samples and `Android-Extension` project as well.

Find their repo here:

1. [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/NavigationAdvancedSample).
2. [Android-Extension](https://github.com/beetlestance/android-extensions).

Let me know if you need anything else from my end. I stuck at this point and already spent few hours but didn't found any solution.

Thanks.